# Qt graphics object that has text, images, and shapes that can resize all elements

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

Using Qt, I need to display instances with graphical elements including image(s), text, and drawn shapes like rectangles.

So far, I achieved this with a QGraphicsItemGroup as the parent, using QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsPixmapItem for images, QLabel for text, and QRect for rectangles. The problem is the text and the rectangles do not scale with the image when I call parent.setScale(0.5f).

Ideally, I would like the graphical elements to scale with each other. It would also be nice if I could set up the scene in Design view to place and size the instances how I want.

Could I use a QGraphicsAnchorLayout? Should I keep using a QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView? What is the best way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the QGraphicsItemGroup did end up working, I just forgot to call addToGroup() on all the other elements.

It's a solution that should work for me, but I'm still open to other suggestions!